# Not loading module config.xml

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, module, configuration

So I've done this probably 20 or 30 times, but this time round something isn't loading right and I've no idea why - and to be honest its driving me mental!

Basic module, declaration file, config file and an index controller. I've included screenshots below so you can see the exact setup. The issue I'm getting is that the module is appearing in System->Config->Advanced, but I've logged the setup XML and my config.xml of my module isn't being included. I've cleared the cache (which is off) and made sure compilation is off.

[image: File tree]
[image: etc/Bluefox_Brands.xml]
[image: etc/config.xml]
[image: IndexController.php]

My router ends up in a 404, by the way...

Thanks all, hopefully some easy points for someone.

Comment: Post code not screenshots. It's easier to copy/paste and test. And what url are you calling and ending up on 404?

Comment: I included screenshots so you could EXACTLY what I had - as I knew it'd be something that was crazy simple and I just wasn't seeing. We've all been there after all. And they were obviously helpful enough, as nachito spotted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Bluefox_Brands.xml XML is invalid. Extra `>`

```
<codePool>local></codePool>
```